# EventHandler not being added to control from code behind

Tags: c#, webforms, eventhandler

I have created a table in a Web Forms User Control that has a tablerow in which is a tablecell with ID="cellButton".
In code behind (C#) I add a Button control to that tablecell using:

```
            Button btn = new Button(); btn.ID = "btnSave" + id;
            btn.Text = "Update";
            btn.Click += new EventHandler(SaveButton_Click);
            btn.CssClass = "btnAction";
            cellButton.Controls.Add(btn);
```

which works perfectly apart from the fact that the EventHandler is not included with the other details (below taken from View Source):

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Orders$btnSave8" value="Update" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Orders_btnSave8" class="btnAction" />
```

The button is displayed but when I click on it the only thing that happens is that it disappears.
Why? What is the cure?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to debug the code of `SaveButton_Click` when you click on the button?

Comment: You won't find the event handler in the tag. It's bound server-side. As for why it's not being triggered, there's not enough information. You need to indicate where in the page lifecycle you're adding the button. Adding a button and then seeing it on the page isn't enough. On postback, it needs to be re-added at a point that allows the event to be triggered. And because you don't re-add it, it doesn't "disappear", it just doesn't appear *again* (that's an important distinction).

Comment: Can you share the code from SaveButton_Click?

Comment: `SaveButton_Click` isn't going to help. The method where the button is being added is what matters. It's likely *not* `Page_Init` or `OnInit`, which is where controls need to be [re-]added (early in the page lifecycle) so that events like `Click` can be fired.